# Selenium Webdriver (Eclipse): importing issues using ctrl +shift +O

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am learning how to use Selenium Webdriver using Eclipse IDE. I am trying to import a browser (for example, Firefox), by using ctrl+shift+O, but it does not seem to work. It just says "0 imports added" at the bottom. What am I doing wrong? This is how my script looks so far (see below). **I have a red squiggly underline below the word "WebDriver" and "FirefoxDriver"**:

```
public class Firefox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mac:

```
Command + Shift + O
```

Windows:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (<-- an 'O' not a zero)

For static import:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>M</kbd>(Source > Add Import) can not only be used to add missing imports. It can also help with static

**Second Edit**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Firefox {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

   }
}
```

1.[Download the selenium jar file](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.0/selenium-java-3.0.1.zip)

2. In Eclipse > Right click on your project or Firefox class > Select  Build path > Configure Build Path .. Select Libraries tab> Add External Jar> Add Selenium Java jar .

3.Click Ok

==========================

**Edit Part Two**

It seems now we need to manually download and set path to the driver executable for Mozilla Firefox.

Following is what you need to do:-

1.[Downlaod Mozilla GeckoDriver latest version for MAC](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.13.0/geckodriver-v0.13.0-macos.tar.gz)

2. Extract on your desired location i.e. c:\GeckoDriver\geckodriver.exe

Now you need to set system property and write following lines to initialize FireFoxDriver object:-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",   "/Users/yourpath/Downloads/geckodriver");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://seleniumhq.com");
```

Thats it!

Comment: thanks @java. I tried manually adding the "import" line on top but it says "**import org.openqa.selenium.firefox** cannot be resolved". And then i added the public class line but it is still showing an "X" on the left of that line saying "cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: does it have anything to do with the proper jar files not being added?

Comment: Yes, you have to add the external jar file

Comment: Do you know which specific jar file is affecting this import from not happening? I added all the jar files i could see in my folder.

Comment: @Faiza_Minnelli I edited again please check the answer!

Comment: OK thanks. I had downloaded the same jar file.. but now i am not seeing the error messages next to the import lines (so that is good). However for the line "**WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();**" I am still seeing the error for "FirefoxDriver" which says the following:

Comment: - Type mismatch: cannot convert from FirefoxDriver to WebDriver
- Cannot instantiate the type FirefoxDriver

- at Firefox.main(Firefox.java:10)

Comment: can you see issues above? @Java

Comment: @Faiza_Minnelli Please check >  Edit Part Two

Comment: ok i am using a MAC OS (64 bit).... which link should I download? @Java

Comment: @Faiza_Minnelli new update click on Downlaod Mozilla GeckoDriver latest version

Comment: OK I did the following. Formatting is matching what you displayed above, but I am still seeing the same issue for FirefoxDriver. It says "Cannot instantiate the type FirefoxDriver" and "cannot convert from FirefoxDriver to WebDriver" @Java

Comment: I downloaded the latest geckoDriver and wrote the path just the way you did.

Comment: @Faiza_Minnelli Still issue ?

Comment: Yeah. Wish I can show you a screenshot of what I have written so far, but I can't in the comment section. I can't move forward with this tutorial without fixing this issue :/ @Java

Comment: @Faiza_Minnelli Make sure you have the latest Firefox  and what is your Java version?

Comment: My FF is up to date. It says it's 51.0.1 (64-bit). Where do I go to check my Java version? Sorry I am new to this stuff... @Java

Comment: If you want to know the "Eclipse" version, its "Kepler Service Release 2".

Comment: @Faiza_Minnelli Open a terminal window. You can find this under Go -> Applications -> Utilities.  In terminal write:  java -version

Comment: OK. This is what i got (See next comment) @Java

Comment: - java version "1.8.0_121"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: @Faiza_Minnelli  try to restart your mac

Comment: Just did and still the same issue @Java